# Why I'm getting "Building MacinTalk voice for asset: (null)" in iOS device test

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I'm executing below code for text-to-speech project on device, but getting error "Building MacinTalk voice for asset: (null)"
Please any help on how I can fix or any tips what's going wrong.

```
 AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Tips For Silicon Valley From A Startup Accelerator In Gaza"];
    [utterance setRate:0.015f];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this on iOS 9 as well but not always.

Answer (score 2):

If it the same as I am seeing then it is not *really* an error - it is an output to the log and a minor annoyance but can be ignored. The reference 'null' is worrying but the speechSynthesizer is still working and talking correctly and users will not see this message on real devices. I have only seen this since iOS9, possibly a log event turned on during development that they forgot to turn off.

Answer (score 2):

I have log error like that (Building MacinTalk voice for asset: (null))
I don't know why, but if your project don't show sound in device I think you forgot allow activating an audio session.

```
import AVFoundation
```

///

```
do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

        do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        }catch{

        }
    }catch{

    }
```